# Public Transport planner for Hanover (Hannover)?

Tags: public-transport, germany, hanover

I'm off to Hanover soon (Hannover in German, that one confused me a bit...), and I need to work out how to get from the airport to my hotel, hotel to the city etc. The hotel's website has some information on that, which referenced trams, but now I want to look up the timings and changes.

My usual first port of a call for public transport information in a foreign city is Google Maps. That seems to know about the local trains (S-Bahn), but not about any buses or trams. So, it appears Google doesn't yet know about all the public transport for the area.

As this is Germany, I'm sure there's an amazing trip planner out there for Hanover, which'll do bus/tram/train/walk/etc. Can anyone point me in the right direction of such a planner? (Ideally one has an English option, but that's not vital)

Comment: Don't forget to look into a [regional train ticket](http://www.bahn.com/i/view/GBR/en/prices/germany/laender-ticket.shtml) if you're going to be traveling through a German region. They cost 22 EUR, cover up to 5 people for the entire day (or an unlimited number of children), and work on most regional and local public transit in the region you select.

Comment: You think Hanover/Hannover is confusing?  Wait till you see Munich/München, Cologne/Köln or Bavaria/Bayern.

Comment: The other day I had a serious hangover in Hanover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The responsible organisation for Hanover is the GVH Hannover, their site in English can be found [here](http://www.gvh.de/index.html?&L=1).

The overview of the [underground/tram](http://www.gvh.de/fileadmin/gvh/downloads/Plaene/Plaene_2013/GVH_Stadtbahn-RZ.pdf).
The overview of all [buses](http://www.gvh.de/fileadmin/gvh/downloads/Plaene/Plaene_2013/GVH_Bus-RZ.pdf). If it is too much info, [here](http://www.gvh.de/busplne.html?&L=1) it is in parts.
The [trains](http://www.gvh.de/fileadmin/gvh/downloads/Plaene/Plaene_2013/GVH_RS-Bahn-RZ.pdf) should not be forgotten.
For convienience you can buy a city planner normally in every store near the train station which looks like [that](http://www.google.de/imgres?q=Stadtplan%20Hannover&start=53&hl=de&biw=1920&bih=982&tbm=isch&tbnid=P-Kcp1NJqkNbTM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.hannover.de/Tourismus/Besucher-Service/Tourist-Information-Hannover/Souvenirs/Karten-Stadtpl%25C3%25A4ne/Stadtplan-Hannover&docid=JMsIoCBzBjMLKM&imgurl=http://www.hannover.de/var/storage/images/hannover.de/tourismus/besucher-service/tourist-information-hannover/souvenirs2/karten-stadtpl%2525C3%2525A4ne/stadtplan-hannover/8003831-1-ger-DE/Stadtplan-Hannover_image_full.jpg&w=775&h=1033&ei=5B-jUcPYE8aqO_b5gMAN&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=1597&vpy=98&dur=1223&hovh=259&hovw=194&tx=126&ty=101&page=2&tbnh=138&tbnw=80&ndsp=77&ved=1t:429,r:16,s:100,i:52).

Comment: And [this](http://www.wetteronline.de/?pid=p_embeddedmaps&ireq=true&src=2vtyp/vermarktung/maps2tiles/p_home/2013/05/27/08/45/M4/p_home.jpeg) is the current weather in Germany :(( . It is currently the coldest weather in Europe, gray, appalling and raining.

Answer (score 11):

The [Deutsche Bahn](http://www.bahn.de/p/view/index.shtml) travel planner covers local (tram & bus) transit in most German cities as well, although it will not display the price.

Otherwise, googling "(city name) Verkehrsbetriebe" will usually lead to the main provider of public transport, the larger of which will have a form for trip planning, [as is the case for Hannover](http://www.uestra.de/186.html?&L=1).

Look for the word "Karte" for [a system map](http://plaene.uestra.de/) if no English option catches your eye.

Answer (score 2):

There's an Android app Öffi, it's the travel planner for Germany and German-speaking countries, it has all public transports and it has interface in English.

Comment: My mistake, than öffi stays